# How to calculate the recurrence relation in this sequence?

Tags: formula

sorry for perhaps stupid question, but I can't calculate recurrence relation (formula for counting the nth term of a sequence) in this sequence:

1, 2, √2, ⁴√8, ⁸√32

I would be very thankful if you can help me!

I have tried many formulas but always have got something wrong. AIs also haven't helped me. I assume that the formula is such that the number is multiplied by 4, and the power of the root by 2, but then either the second or third number interferes.

Comment: Pardon me, but how is your question related to [computer] programming?

Comment: Here is the site for theoretical computer science problems: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ This kind of question is not on topic on StackOverflow, since it's not about code, software, or a specific algorithm, but it seems like it might be a better fit on CS.SE. Since you've already found the solution on your own, it's probably not worthwhile to ask for *this* question to be migrated there, but you may want to keep the distinction in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has solved: n = √(n-1)*(n-2)

Comment: It has to be more descriptive

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).